# Issue in reading spss file in python

Tags: python

I have installed pyreadstat using the below comment

"pip install pyreadstat",

but when I tried to import pyreadstat it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyreadstat'"

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

I would check these things:

1. When you run pip, maybe that command exited with error so pyreadstat never got installed? Do pip list to check if the library is indeed installed.
2. Maybe you have several versions of python installed and you are using pip with one of them and later another one when trying to import pyreadstat. Check where pip is installed with "which pip" or "where pip" if on windows, and check that the python interpreter is in the same location.
3. Maybe pyreadstat was installed in a location that is not in sys.path for some reason. When installing with pip check carefully where it was installed and then check this folder is in sys.path. IF not, include it.